# Setting up Firebase Simple Login for iOS with Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase

I'm setting up Firebase for the first time with iOS and I have some problems with the Simple Login with Facebook authentication setup it seems.

### The issue

I am running this in the Simulator - which may be my problem, as the simulator doesn't have the Facebook App or the Facebook integration? But I currently don't have a Apple Developer account.

I expect this to trigger the Facebook authentication view in the Facebook app, or if the app isn't installed on the device, switch over to Safari and using the normal authentication page, but nothing happens.

### Setup

As far as I comprehend, these are the minimum requirements to get it running:

1. A Facebook app with:

   - Website with Facebook Login URL defined as: https://auth.firebase.com/auth/facebook/callback
   - A native iOS app Bundle ID matching the Bundle identifier in the XCode project target summary
2. An iOS project with:

   - Link binary with Libraries:

     - Firebase.framework
     - Foundation.framework (obviously... :) )
     - libicucore.lib
     - Security.framework
     - CFNetwork.framework
     - FirebaseAuthClient.framework
     - Accounts.framework
     - Social.framework
   - -ObjC under Other linker flag
   - Matching Bundle identifier with with the Facebook app Bundle ID
3. Facebook app ID and App Secret added to Auth in Firebase Forge

View my Facebook app setup here (Screen shot): http://flashpatric.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/facebookSetup.png

**Code:**

```
Firebase* ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://xxx.firebaseio.com"];
FirebaseAuthClient* authClient = [[FirebaseAuthClient alloc] initWithRef:ref];

[authClient loginToFacebookAppWithId:@"xxx-facebook-app-id-xxx" permissions:@[@"email"] withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, FAUser *user) {
    if (error != nil) {
        // There was an error logging in
        NSLog(@"There was an error logging in: code = %d", [error code]);
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    } else {
        // We have a logged in facebook user
        NSLog(@"We have a logged in facebook user: %@",user);
    }
}];

[authClient checkAuthStatusWithBlock:^(NSError* error, FAUser* user) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Oh no! There was an error performing the check %@",error);
    } else if (user == nil) {
        NSLog(@"No user is logged in");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"There is a logged in user %@",user);
    }
}];
```

**The output:**

```
2013-03-27 11:10:08.900 firebase[18729:1303] There was an error logging in: code = 6
2013-03-27 11:10:08.905 firebase[18729:1303] Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=6 The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 6.)
2013-03-27 11:10:08.924 firebase[18729:c07] No user is logged in
```

OK, am I missing something obvious here, or is it just the iOS Simulator issue that is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a couple of things to use Facebook auth, which should work on the simulator:

1. An app setup on Facebook. It sounds like you have this already
2. A Facebook account setup on your simulator. Currently, the FirebaseAuthClient doesn't interact with the Facebook app, it just uses the native Facebook integration built in to iOS.
3. Make sure you have the latest version of the FirebaseAuthClient. As of now, it's 1.0.1, and you can get it here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/downloads.html
4. Make sure you have enabled Facebook auth in Forge. From your description it looks like you have done this already.

My guess, from the error that you are getting, is that you are missing step 2. On your simulator, go to Settings -> Facebook and log in to an account.

Comment: Yes, thank you Greg. I was missing something obvious... ;) I actually thought there was no Facebook integration in the simulator and never checked the settings for that.

Comment: @Greg Soltis: I had the same setup but whenever I add FacebookSDK to the linked libraries, I get: "Trying to log in to wrong app" on the console log. It works fine w/out FacebookSDK though. Any idea why?

Comment: Hmm, odd. Does it happen if you completely uninstall the app and then try again with the FacebookSDK?

Comment: Yes it does. I already wrote an email to Firebase support but no proper response yet as of the moment.

Comment: Can you double check that your .plist file is set up properly per the end of step #5 here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/